# Force loading a single attribute with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to find a way to update a single attribute of a model without it getting dirty. Just like `Store.load` but with just a single attribute.

The use case is that I want to upload an avatar image (which cannot be done with the current adapter's semantics AFAIK). I do it against a particular API endpoint and I afterwards I want to update the user with the resulting URL (so all his avatar appearances get updated).

I am in the context of a profile edition, so if I just load the whole user I loose all the changes of the form (because the values get overriden).

Is there any way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways, but I haven't tried them. (They're both just workarounds)

You can set a user's property that is not a DS.attr.  If it's a normal property, it shouldn't dirty the record.

If url is a database attribute, then create a computed property that listens to URL and use that in your templates.

```
App.User = Em.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  URL: function() {
    return this.get('url');
  }.property('url')
});
```

And then `user.set('URL', imageUrl)`

Another way could be to transition the record to the `clean` state.

`user.get('stateManager').send('becameClean');`

The second method is an ugly hack though.

Comment: Those two approaches look really fine. I tried with the first one, but I really am not comfortable with having two methods to do the same thing (and with slightly different names). I'm gonna mark it as valid since I don't think there's many other options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could model 'Avatar' separately, as a model in itself instead of an attribute. Then, that model can be updated via the store without worrying about conflicting changes with the rest of the User model.

Comment: Thanks! I kinda do, but then it would have to have an ID, right? I could always use its parent's ID but doesn't sound ideal.